# mySQL - Find find unique columns based on duplicates in another column

Tags: mysql, sql, duplicates

I have been investigating [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60334514/mysql-find-duplicates-based-on-another-column-value) but it is not quite what I need and I do not understand how to solve it.

Table: companies

Columns: id, cust_number, cust_name

There may be many records with the same cust_number, but all such records should have identical cust_name.

The query I am trying to write should display all records where this is not the case - like this:

```
| id | cust_number | cust_name |
| -- | ----------- | --------- | 
| 10 |    800      | Acme LTD  | 
| 11 |    700      | Globex    | 
| 12 |    800      | Acme LTD  | 
| 13 |    444      | Globex    | 
| 14 |    800      | Acme LTT  |
```

From the table above the query should result in:

```
| id | cust_number | cust_name |
| -- | ----------- | --------- | 
| 10 |    800      | Acme LTD  | 
| 12 |    800      | Acme LTD  | 
| 14 |    800      | Acme LTT  |
```

Because there are more than 1 records with the same cust_number but all 3 records does not have identical cust_name.

Thanks for all help!

Comment: Please show us your query what you have tried?

Comment: Your expected output does not match the description.

Comment: @AmanjotKaur, I have only tried the query in the post I linked to.

Comment: @SalmanA, are you sure? The 3 cust_names are not all identical.

Comment: @SalmanA it does, so long as you account for the fact that string comparison in MySQL will evaluate 'Acme LTD' and 'Acme Ltd' as equal, whereas this is _not_ what the author wants.

Comment: @SalmanA, I understand. I have modified the orginal post. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `EXISTS` to check for records with the same `cust_number` but different name.

```
SELECT c1.id,
       c1.cust_number,
       c1.cust_name
       FROM companies c1
       WHERE EXISTS (SELECT *
                            FROM companies c2
                                 WHERE c2.cust_number = c1.cust_number
                                       AND c2.cust_name <> c1.cust_name);
```

Comment: I have tried this but it does not return anything. Please note that it should show records with the same cust_number, not the same ID...

Comment: @oldeagle: Changed `id` to `cust_number`, see the edit.

Comment: Thanks, sticky bit. That worked but the query takes a very long time to run. I may have to think of another way to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming MySQL 8.0, you can use window functions for this:

```
select id, cust_number, cust_name
from (
    select 
        t.*,
        min(cust_name) over(partition by cust_number) min_cust_name,
        max(cust_name) over(partition by cust_number) max_cust_name
    from mytable t
) t
where min_cust_name <> max_cust_name
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably an issue you're running into here is that (usually) string comparison in MySQL is case-insensitive - see "[How can I make SQL case sensitive string comparison on MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5629111/how-can-i-make-sql-case-sensitive-string-comparison-on-mysql)
".

i.e. `SELECT ('Acme LTD' = 'Acme Ltd');` returns 1 or `TRUE`.

You can circumvent this by comparing the binary representation of the strings; `SELECT (BINARY 'Acme LTD' = BINARY 'Acme Ltd');` returns 0.

---

With that in mind, the following query should return what you're looking for;

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.id
              , t1.cust_number
              , t1.cust_name
FROM my_table t1
         JOIN my_table t2 ON t2.cust_number = t1.cust_number AND
                             (BINARY t2.cust_name <> BINARY t1.cust_name)
ORDER BY t1.id;
```